# Differences in gradient and optimization between a dense layer with NxM dimensions and M separate Nx1 dense layers in PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am wondering how these two design choices would impact the calculation of gradients and the overall optimization process during training.

1. How would gradient calculation during backpropagation be affected in each structure?
2. Would there be differences in how the gradients flow back into the network?
3. Would these different network structures potentially require or benefit from different optimization algorithms or learning rates?
   My goal is to better understand the implications (both potential benefits and possible drawbacks) of each model structure choice from the perspective of gradient calculation and optimization.

Any insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I also attempted an experiment where I initialized the weights of both models to ones. However, when I compared the gradients after backpropagation, they were different.

```
tensor([[ 0.0289026424,  0.0164458379, -0.0429413468, -0.0317727998,
         -0.0011618818,  0.0309777111,  0.0496413819, -0.0330999792,
         -0.0217525940, -0.0376570895,  0.0238987785, -0.0303875748,
          0.0422640890, -0.0327035226, -0.0046056593,  0.0095992200,
          0.0047464888, -0.0015923150, -0.0349406302,  0.0358588137,
          0.0109524736,  0.0521549769,  0.0092769144,  0.0338292755,
          0.0418556146,  0.0403830707,  0.0027946709, -0.0142157376,
          0.0573743209,  0.0421377942,  0.0161724705,  0.0135669028,
          0.0103750098,  0.0048434297, -0.0176108982, -0.0011629635,
          0.0177134797,  0.0047528706,  0.0455351323, -0.0127471210,
         -0.0103122834,  0.0092379786, -0.0011389051,  0.0214950778,
          0.0423520021,  0.0157480091,  0.0166458990, -0.0457958765]])
tensor([[ 0.0289026424,  0.0164458416, -0.0429413430, -0.0317727998,
         -0.0011618854,  0.0309777092,  0.0496413782, -0.0330999792,
         -0.0217525922, -0.0376570858,  0.0238987822, -0.0303875823,
          0.0422640815, -0.0327035226, -0.0046056607,  0.0095992228,
          0.0047464883, -0.0015923139, -0.0349406339,  0.0358588099,
          0.0109524755,  0.0521549769,  0.0092769163,  0.0338292755,
          0.0418556109,  0.0403830633,  0.0027946699, -0.0142157376,
          0.0573743209,  0.0421377942,  0.0161724724,  0.0135669019,
          0.0103750126,  0.0048434315, -0.0176109001, -0.0011629632,
          0.0177134816,  0.0047528730,  0.0455351323, -0.0127471173,
         -0.0103122853,  0.0092379786, -0.0011389013,  0.0214950833,
          0.0423520021,  0.0157480109,  0.0166459009, -0.0457958728]])
torch.Size([48])
Size of gradient for layer 12 is torch.Size([1, 48])
Is gradient the same for layer 12?  False
```